# Need to create a link to a qr code on a phone home screen

Tags: qr-code, homescreen, home-screen-widget

This might be too simple to find an easy solution for.

We are moving to a system where our staff clock on and clock off using a QR or Bar code.
We can provide each staff member with their own QR code on a sticker and they clock on/off by passing it under the scanner as they arrive/depart.  (Typically this is stuck on the back of their phone.)

A better option would be to display the code on the screen of the phone itself.  This can be done by saving the code in the photo gallery and displaying it for scanning but this is quite fiddly and the whole point is to streamline the process.

Any suggestions?

I thought there might be a way to create a home screen icon that links to an image and displays it but if so it alludes me.
Failing this I thought there might be an app to achieve the same result but I have not been able to find one.

Answer (score 0):

First, have a imgur or any other photo sharing accounts. Then, put all the staff's qrcodes in there and assign each their own qrcode link which they can add to home screen

The link will look something like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3anRj.png

Comment: I had not thought of that but it is an option - putting them on the company website.  I would still prefer that they do not have to download it each time and one issue is that we want staff to only access their own code but we could wrap it in a password. - Thanks!